# Elixir: Cannot access struct

Tags: struct, elixir

I'm trying to get structs to work but none of the documented examples on the Internet or printed books work.

This example on the web site (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/elixir/elixir_structs.htm) also shows the same problem:

```
defmodule User do
   defstruct name: "John", age: 27
end

john = %User{}

#To access name and age of John, 
IO.puts(john.name)
IO.puts(john.age)
```

I get the error cannot access struct User, the struct was not yet defined or the struct is being accessed in the same context that defines it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're probably trying to run this using `elixir <filename.exs>` while the book you may have seen similar code in was most likely typing the code into `iex`. (Edit: the code on the page you linked to has been lifted straight from the official tutorial (http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html) which *is* typing that code into `iex`). This will work in `iex` but not in an `exs` script; this is a limitation of the way Elixir "scripts" are compiled and evaluated.

I usually wrap the code in another function (and possibly another module) and invoke that at the end when I have to create and use structs in `exs` scripts:

```
$ cat a.exs
defmodule User do
  defstruct name: "John", age: 27
end

defmodule Main do
  def main do
    john = %User{}
    IO.puts(john.name)
    IO.puts(john.age)
  end
end

Main.main
$ elixir a.exs
John
27
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly this "limitation" is? Does this only apply to `.exs`-files?

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping struct creation and other related operations in a module should be sufficient.

```
defmodule Customer do
  defstruct name: "", company: ""
end

defmodule BugReport do
  defstruct owner: %Customer{}, details: "", severity: 1
end

defmodule Playground do
  report = %BugReport{owner: %Customer{name: "X", company: "X"}}
  IO.inspect report
end
```

**$ elixir ./your_filename.ex**